# Problem with Oracle Job Scheduling

Tags: oracle, jobs, materialized-view

I have a job that refreshes a materialised view refresh group on Oracle 19c. I wanted to refresh the group daily at midnight - `trunc(sysdate)`?  The job was made using using the following PL/SQL:

```
  BEGIN
  DBMS_REFRESH.MAKE (
        name => 'REFG_1',
        list => '', 
        next_date => trunc(sysdate), 
        interval => 'SYSDATE + 1',
        implicit_destroy => FALSE, 
        rollback_seg => '',
        push_deferred_rpc => TRUE, 
        refresh_after_errors => FALSE);
  END;
  /
```

The MVs are getting refreshed daily.  However, they are refreshing at 11:26AM  (this coincides with the time I originally created the job).

How do I create this job to ensure it refreshes at midnight each night?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interval should be `trunc(sysdate)+1` to mean midnight tomorrow.

Your `next_date` will be evaluated to midnight today (in the past) so the first refresh will happen ASAP. You probably want this to also be tomorrow midnight

Answer (score 0):

The next execution time (`SYSDATE+1` in your case) of your job is evaluated when the previous job has been finished. Thus it will be shifted more and more.

Either use `TRUNC(SYSDATE)+1` or change to modern [Scheduler Jobs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/scheduse.htm#ADMIN034) were you have more freedom.